# Open "steam://..." link via nodeJS and Chrome

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, steam

steam provides links to inspect items in 3D by opening the game and the specific 3D model. Such a link looks like this:

```
steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198808861484A14783070567D17060211998222859457
```

If this link is clicked in a browser, it asks confirmation to open the "Steam Client Bootstrapper" and then runs the game (or you check a box so it doesn't ask that again).

**I would like to make a node script, that would open such a link (probably via chrome) and runs the game.**

I tried chrome-launcher:

```
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');

inspect("steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198808861484A14783070567D17060211998222859457")

function inspect(link){
    chromeLauncher.launch({
      startingUrl: link
    }).then(chrome => {
      console.log(`Chrome debugging port running on ${chrome.port}`);
    });
}
```

and also the opn module:

```
const opn = require('opn');

inspect("steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S76561198808861484A14783070567D17060211998222859457")

function inspect(link){
    opn(link, {app: 'chrome'}); 
}
```

Both of these have the same result:

- Chrome opens up
- Address bar is empty
- Nothing happens

Any idea on how I could do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Steam browser protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) works about the same on any system -- click a `steam://` link or open a browser page with one and it will open Steam with whatever it is as arguments. The first time that this is used, from each browser IIRC, it will ask if it should launch Steam from a shortcut. Users can deny the request, deny forever, or allow forever (of course it can be changed in settings). The issue here may be that you're opening it with a browser running as part of your app. Have you tried opening it in the default browser?

Comment: @l3l_aze if I leave out the argument that tells it which app to use, it opens it in the default browser, according to opn's documentation. Didn't think of that for some reason. I'm not home at the moment. Will try later and report back. Thanks so far!

Comment: No problem; hope it works for you -- good luck!

Comment: @l3l_aze it worked perfectly fine without the app parameter (using default browser). Thanks!

Comment: Nice; glad you're back on track again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the app parameter so it uses the standard browser.